# Would putting out mealworms with supplements on be harmful to birds?

Tags: birds

Not **strictly** a pet question, but I think this is the most appropriate place.

We have a leopard gecko, and I use EarthPro A as a supplement, which is sprinkled onto her mealworms. After a few days, the mealworms get tossed outside and replaced with new ones that have been gut-loaded with carrot peel. The local birds then find the mealworms in the garden and snaffle them up.

Is there any cause for concern, if native species such as robins, thrushes, starlings etc... eat the mealworms which have a small amount of residual supplement on? Or, am I just going to end up with a load of hench birds knocking on the window asking for more supplements?

[image]

Comment: If it is really Mg only, there should be no concern... but I am not an expert in birds, so this as comment

Comment: Updated the question, I got the product name wrong. It's actually this https://www.arcadiareptile.com/earthpro/supplements/earthpro-a/

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the nutritional requirements of wild birds to feel confident putting up an answer, but as they are eating a broad variety of things and not just your mealworms, I would be very surprised if there was an issue. Also, after a couple of days there is probably very little supplement left on the mealworms anyway. (I take it the gecko only gets fed every couple of days?)

Comment: She has her mealworms changed every couple of days, yes. But she always has food available.